# No Permission to create directory

Tags: vb.net

I want to create this folder:

> C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Sub1\Sub2

using this code:

```
IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData) & "\" & "Sub1\Sub2\")
```

On my machine (with admin rights) this works well.
On a user's machine (withouut admin rights) it throws an exception "not allowed to create directory", but the user can create these directories by hand using Windows Explorer.

So it doesn't seem to be a general permission problem, because the user can create the directories manually. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Show the contain of `Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData`, on user's machine

Comment: Have you tried it on another place on the machine of the user, maybe in their local documents folder?

Nothing wrong with the code you basically answered the question yourself already the user doesn't have sufficient rights for the `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local` folder. Make sure the user has write permissions

Comment: User has write permissions (he can create the Directories). And after he creates them by hand my software is able to store files in them (in the user's user context). Strange

Comment: Have you tried letting the code create a folder in a different place on the machine

Comment: Double check the `[username]` thing?

Comment: @Jimi that will not be the problem since the path is determined by the `Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData` part this will automatically grab the current users folder

Comment: @BRoebie  Yep, that was too cryptic. I meant, I might be useful to check whether the User rights on the parent folder don't conflict with the Admin group rights. The logged in User may be in the Admin group. If the access right on the parent folder(s) have been modified, there might be a conflict of access rights. In this case, acting as a User without admin rights and without impersonation, generated an Access Denied. But, I'ld use `Path.Combine` to generated the final path. You never know what the actual code is and where it takes it's names from. It may be just a malformed path.

Comment: The combined path is C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Sub1\Sub2 (of course is [username] a placeholder). - so it seems to be correct. What I'm wondering about (and what my problem seems to be): Why can the user create the paths with the Explorer without authorization problems? Can the mentioned points from you still be relevant (e.g. permissions of the parent folder)?

Comment: Not a solution but a suggestion: better use `Path.Combine` instead of string concatenation.
`IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "Sub1", "Sub2"))`